# Which countries are "Muslim countries"?

Tags: culture, terminology, countries, islam, religion

In [the question about drinking beer in Dubai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3410/will-i-get-in-trouble-if-i-drink-beer-in-public-in-dubai) it arose that the term "Muslim country" can be seen as one where the laws of the country are affected by the rules of the religion (like Dubai), whereas other countries may be secular countries with overwhelmingly Muslim populations (like Turkey).

So which of the countries that have high Muslim populations are not secular and have laws based on the religion?

(I know this is asking for a list but it's a small, definite, closed set so not "too broad" in the sense possible with many questions.)

Comment: Perhaps if you made it "how can I tell if a country is a Muslim country or a secular country where many Muslims live?" it would not really be a list/poll question any more

Comment: Well to me it's not even certain that "Muslim country" has such a fixed meaning, which is why I included the terminology tag. Maybe I should ask a companion question on english.SE? In any case I'll monitor the feedback here and reword my question if it makes sense to me. I think it's really immune to the list/poll prohibition to a sensible interpretation of that rule if not a literal interpretation so let's se...

Comment: @hippietrail “Muslim country” does not have a fixed meaning, any more than “Christian country” or “beer-drinking country” does. If you don't know what someone meant by “Muslim country”, ask them.

Comment: Sometimes more than one person is using the term and you can't tell if they are using it in the same way. For example, the asker of a question and the answerers and commenters. And of course sometimes people use these terms not realizing they are fuzzy and might not even have thought they had to choose from among the various uses to know what they meant.

Comment: Well to Muslim countries it does have a fixed meaning, the definition of "Muslim country" is: A religious state governed solely by Islamic law, no other law may contradict Islamic law nor rule beside it. A civil state adopting some parts of Islamic law (due to a substantial part of population being Muslims) is NOT a Muslim country and is usually seen by some Muslim countries as a non respectful loose society. So if just one little thing isn’t done exactly as Islamic law says then it's not a Muslim country it's a country with Muslims.

Comment: @ Gilles and @msk since you have totally opposite yet certain answers, does either of you have a reference to support your views?

Comment: My best reference is my personal experience, I am Muslim, I am Egyptian and i have lived in most of the countries i am talking about. However there are many other references but only in Arabic and some of them carry the meaning to a more detailed and complicated level (mostly extremists who want the whole world to be one big Muslim country) you must know these people well and understand their culture to know who is who and what is reliable. Now I'm not saying that i am correct and anyone else is not. The term might not have a fixed meaning in other cultures

Comment: which is why I started with "To Muslim countries" since it has a fixed clear definition to them. This was the official Saudi Arabian definition, other governments and organizations might have some slightly more restricted definitions but this is the most common and inclusive definition most agreed on. This is what the Salafi groups mean when they say they want Egypt to be an Islamic country, and it is what the Muslim Brotherhood believe when they use the term.

Comment: It is usually very hard to find a "reliable" reference for anything in the Middle East, but this one is very easy. Many references (in Arabic) are available on the web, just search for تعريف الدولة الاسلامية. (definition of Muslim country/Islamic state) in Arabic. One of the references which I think is reliable is http://www.e-cfr.org/ar/bo/28.doc

Comment: I see two complicating factors. The way the English term "Muslim country" is used in English by English speakers may have different senses than how it is used in translation or how its literal equivalents are used in Arabic. The other is that "Muslim country" and "Islamic state" are not necessarily exact synonyms. I think there are some good questions for **[English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/)**.

Comment: i know my answer is kinda late, but just as i see that lebanon is being considered a muslim country? how come? i am lebanese and a christian, we are 50% christians 50% muslims.
Lebanon is a republic and democratic , no sharia law, and alchool is sold at every single city.<br>

In brief, lebanon and syria are the only two nations in the middle east that are secular,republics (although christians in syria are fewer than lebanon in proportion).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image: Countries following traditional Islamic Sharia law]

[**(Full resolution)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Countries_with_Sharia_rule.png)

Traditional Islamic law is known as [Sharia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia). By and large, countries following it or having a dual system of civil law as well as Sharia is depicted in this map. As a traveller, this is something you need to watch out for as a country you're visiting may have laws not commonly found in civil law found in most other countries. What makes it tough to understand is the uneven interpretation each country has. For instance, playing card games in public is not allowed in Malaysia as it is considered a form of gambling (even if you aren't gambling), yet alcohol (which is prohibited by Islamic law) is sold openly. Most locals will be willing to point out to you if you commit a *faux pas*, but once you have been to a couple of Muslim countries you will get a hang of the basic rules in addition to traditional civil law that you need to be aware of.

Comment: This reminds me that I just learned that backgammon has been banned in Turkey for similar reasons. All games which use dice are considered gambling whether you are actually gambling or not!

Comment: What's your source for this map?

Comment: It's kinda not clear but the map source is the linked Wikipedia article on Sharia law.

Answer (score 10):

I can answer about the Middle East & North Africa only (the politically so-called "Arab World")

Egypt and Tunisia are not Muslim Countries since Islamic law is only one of the sources of legislation, not the only one, and used only in specific cases.

Muslim Countries are ones like Saudi Arabia, Iran, Kuwait...etc (religious states) whose law is only and fully based on Islamic law (Sharia) i.e. their law is the Islamic law, while in Egypt and others (civil states) the law is Egyptian law and when made the sources for making it were many such as French law and Islamic law, depending on what part of the law is being made (criminal, commercial, family law, personal affairs...etc) but every country has its own traditions, it's not just whether the law is Islamic or not since there are also different interpretations of Islamic law.

I would personally categorize them in three categories:

1. Extremely conservative - Religious states (this is where you really need to be careful)
   which include: Saudi Arabia, Kuwait, Yemen, Iran, Iraq, Oman, Libya
2. Moderate - usually civil states (you can still have fun in specified ways and certain parts) include: Jordan, UAE, Syria, Qatar, Sudan, Bahrain
3. Open minded - civil states, usually secular, include: Tunisia, Algeria, Morocco, Egypt, Lebanon

But again every country has its own traditions. For example UAE and Qatar are religiously oriented but serve alcohol and are among the top countries for prostitution. however Egypt which is a civil state and serves alcohol among many things against Islamic law can be very conservative in some districts, example: you cant wear a short skirt in the poorer parts while in Sharm el Sheikh you can sit topless on some beaches.

Anyway in most of the countries I’ve mentioned foreigners are somewhat exempted from traditions applying to locals or at least they forgive you for being a foreigner, there isn’t a case where they will forbid you to do something or punish you legally (except in the extremely conservative) but if you're wearing something too sexy (as a woman) in a common poor district you will get people staring at you the whole time and probably hitting on you, which can be very annoying. While in other parts of the same city you can do all you can think of, the best thing is to have a guide from the country who is open-minded and well educated, not too common because you will get too much wrong information from them.