# About Dubai, hotel as an unmarried couple but with a twist

Tags: hotels, dubai, middle-east, abu-dhabi

Alright, so everything is already booked, hotel, plane tickets etc, we're both aware of the laws and such regarding behaviour and living in the same hotel as an unmarried couple.

My girlfriend was feeling anxious about it and chose to contact the hotel via an e-mail asking if there's any problem with not beeing married...her full name is displayed in the e-mail, anyone know what to do now?

The hotel is booked in my name btw.

EDIT: The one that answered made a CC as well to another one in the hotel… is this normal?

Comment: No one cares.. especially the hotel, as long as you [don't make out in public or attract attention](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/travelling-as-unmarried-couple-in-dubai).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real problem is if you are creating a ruckus or some other disturbance and the hotel has to call in the local authorities.

Otherwise, as long as you keep your [PDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_display_of_affection) in check, you will have no problems in Dubai.

Keep in mind that some hotels are more tolerant than others to unmarried couples.

Comment: How would i know if a hotel is tolerant?? It's a european five-star chain, do you think there will be a problem?

Comment: I doubt it, but have hope that usually this check is done on GCC citizens and residents. At foreign chains its not that big of a problem.