# Can a mixed-Muslim unmarried couple share hotel rooms in Indonesia?

Tags: legal, hotels, indonesia, religion, sex

I am a **muslima** with **Moroccan** passport, and my boyfriend is European. Do you think that we might have problems sharing a room in Indonesia? We do not plan on going to Aceh. We will mostly go to Yogjakarta, Borneo, Gili Islands and Bali.

What kind of trouble can we get into if any issue? Will we be just able to book separate rooms if anything occurs? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travelling as an unmarried Western couple in Indonesia](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60979/travelling-as-an-unmarried-western-couple-in-indonesia)

Comment: @JonathanReez in this case it may warrant it's own question due to the fact that one of the travelers is muslim, which I believe may have different implications with regards to activities they may perform together and how they conduct themselves around each other.

Comment: Mentioning whether the OP visibly looks like a Muslim (e.g. clothing, headgear) might significantly influence the validity of the answer, so it would be a sensible information to add to the question.

Comment: Not really. I don't wear hijab, and I've been living in Europe for someyears now. They might mistake me for a European if not for my passport.

Comment: @vsz  I am sorry, but saying "visibly looks like a Muslim"   There are actually a few other cultures other than Islam that wear clothing similar to the hijab.   Not trying to rant, just a little tired of stereotyping of any variety towards any group.

Comment: @NZKshatriya : but it is the core of this question, because the question asks how they will be perceived by the local population. Similarly, being male or female can be a very important information, because in some cultures they are expected to behave very differently; and also, being identified as a member of a certain religion by the local population can also have some impact on how you are welcomed by them. So those kinds of information are important to consider when traveling to such regions.  Please look up what "stereotyping" means before you accuse me of doing it.

Comment: @vsz  "looks like a muslim"  with your addition of "clothing/headgear"  Clothing and headgear does not make a Muslim.  One cannot tell a Muslim based on clothing.  To say people who wear X clothing are Y, is stereotyping.  Have a nice day.

Comment: @NZKshatriya : For those who might have misunderstood me, please understand "visibly looks like ..." as if I had written "would be identified by most onlookers as ..."

Comment: @NZKshatriya "_people who wear X clothing **are** Y_" would be stereotyping, but recognising that "_people who wear X clothing **may be thought of** as Y_" [by the local population: the views of which the OP is concerned about] is not; it's just accepting reality.

Comment: @Joel "Muslima" means female Muslim. It's not a typo.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I also posted an answer in the linked thread, though your case is slightly different. For reference, I lived in Java and now in Bali.

It's not impossible that there are *some* hotels that will give you trouble, though I find it highly unlikely with neither of you actually being Indonesian. As usual, money speaks and most places would rather make money than enforce religious traditions. Especially in tourist locations (and I doubt you'll go that far 'off the beaten path' that I would not consider it a tourist place)

I can speak from personal experience that I did manage to rent a room with my Indonesian Muslim former girlfriend before.

I can assure you that on Bali and the Gilis you will have no trouble, extremely unlikely in Jogja too, but in some remote places in Borneo it's possible (but still unlikely) you'll have to try another hotel.

Comment: I traveled around Indonesia for a month+ (and also Malaysia for a month+) with my Thai girlfriend, who everyone mistook to be Indonesian everywhere, and no one ever said a word (or even gave a dirty look) about us sharing a room. We did stray off the beaten track, but not too far off.

Answer (score 18):

You are an unmarried couple of mixed religion. But do you have to disclose either?

The easiest solution, *if neither of you has any objection to doing so*, is faking both a marriage and a shared religion.

Most likely it's enough to just not disclose anything that may lead them to think otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just concerned if they see my passport while checking in hotels, they'll have different attitude than with western european tourists.

Comment: "Faking a marriage" In fact most people will assume you are married, as the alternative is unthinkable to them, so just don't tell them otherwise. If one of you is Muslim they will assume the other is too, so, again, don't contradict them. In fact don't mention it at all.

Comment: Thank you! Are police-raid in hotels something common there? I mean, cant it get worse than just having to book separate rooms?

Comment: It's not illegal to be in the same room together with someone of the opposite gender. And though technically by law you're not allowed to have sex before marriage, I doubt any tourist couple ever got arrested for that. And how would they prove you're not married anyway? A hotel may be able to reject you, but law enforcement acting on this? I've never heard of hotel raids anyway. I think you may be mistaking Indonesia for an extremist country.

Comment: @sbyd I used to (briefly) managed hotel in Aceh and the Gili. The police never ever checked the marital status of anybody. Anyway, read my answer below: your situation is legal. And the comment of RedSonja is 200% true

Comment: @sbyd : During ramadan some religious organization may pester the police to raid for unmarried couples, but even then they only target cheap motels or shady prostitution fronts. They never target tourist destinations.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek Actually, in areas with shariah law like Aceh, two unrelated people of the opposite sex being in a closed space without a guardian *is* illegal (*khalwat*, proximity).  But even in Aceh this is not enforced for foreigners.

Comment: @jpatokal well you say areas like Aceh but as far as I know Aceh is the only area with shariah in Indonesia, unless I'm mistaken? And the OP mentioned not going there.

Answer (score 18):

Law says extra-marital sex is forbidden for Indonesian. Foreigner do whatever they please.

And the mixed religion couple is no problem either. There are many mixed religion couple in Indonesia. They have to get married in Singapore, but this is a totally legal (and admitted) situation.

Even in Aceh (I know Aceh quite well) you won't have any problem.

Answer (score 14):

Haha.  I traveled around Indonesia with a woman who was in fact my wife, but she carried a different country's passport and we certainly didn't bring a marriage license with us.   Nobody challenged us -- that may have been the wedding rings or the two small children in tow, or just the fact that hotel staff have better things to do with their time than turn away paying customers.

Comment: I don't really think your experience is relevant to the OP.  The "two small children in tow" will have a huge effect.  Everyone will assume you are married (it's a common presumption even in the UK).  On the other hand, if a couple turn up at a hotel with different surnames in the UK, the assumption will be that they are *not* married (although nobody will care).

Answer (score 5):

I'll share my experience now that I have travelled and came back from Indonesia.
Absolutely no problem at all. In most of the hotels, they didn't even asked about the religion. Some did, but more in a friendly, curious way. We always stated that we are a married couple, just in case.
We slept in hotels in Jogjakarta, Jakarta, Cemoro Lewang, Banyuwangi, Semarang, Ubud, Gili Air and Sanur.
Hope it helps somebody in the same situation.

Answer (score 3):

Well, "Indonesia" is a big word. And a big world by itself.

First of all, it all comes to who is the subject: Muslim law has nothing to say over kafir, it's (mostly) their own problem what they do with their lives. So, when it's about touristic areas or hotels for tourists, you are mostly free to do whatever you want.

This does not apply, anyway, to privately owned places; in short, if you book a guest house or an apartment, or things like AirBnB...the owner has all the rights to prohibit your staying once he discovers that you are an unmarried couple;  I've seen myself this in a couple of place in Indonesia, there were signs stating it.

But keep in mind that all of this depends on the island, too, and the area:

- Bali is out of question, it is the only big Indonesian island to not
  be Muslim, so they never make troubles there.
- Gili is another touristic destination, so they'll just ignore mostly everything
- Jawa can be complicate depending on the area. Basically it's mostly Muslim, but there are part of Jawa which are more free and some which are more strict. But again, if you limit yourself to normal hotels nobody will ever have something to say. Maybe in rural areas do not kiss in public, but Yogja is hardly rural :-) (while I hade my share of shivers, I must admit it, in Lumajang)

Final point is, obviously, if you are recognizable as a Muslim. That the case, it can become very complicate even in a normal hotel as someone can get offended by your lack of respect for the tradition (not me, ok? Just saying, not implying anything), but as a Muslim yourself you already know it, and anyway you wrote in comments that you are not recognizable as such.